# Why is the HOST version of my CUDA function not executing?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cuda, binary-search, thrust

I wrote a CUDA program that runs 1,000,000 binary searches (upper bound) on 1,000,000 different arrays with 100 elements each.  For simplicity's sake, all the 1,000,000 arrays have been combined/flattened into one massive array with 100,000,000 elements.  Keep in mind, the search values for each binary search tree have been "canned" (a constant number is filling the place of where a random number will eventually be used).

I am trying to benchmark the speed-up (or speed-loss) of my Nvidia graphics card compared to my CPU.  The code below describes my current program but the CPU portion keeps coming up with timings of "0" [seconds] and my breakpoints using Visual Studio 2013 are seemingly ignored.  Any ideas as to what's going on?  I have a suspicion that the Thrust functions I am using (or failing to use) may be to blame.

My code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <thrust\random.h>
#include <thrust\generate.h>
#include <thrust\copy.h>
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

void fillArrayWithRandom(float* inputArray, int inputN)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inputN; i++)
    {
        inputArray[i] = (float)rand() / float(RAND_MAX);
    }
}

__global__ void warmUp()
{
}

__host__ __device__ int findTarget(float* inputArray, int startingIndex, int endingIndex, float targetValue)
{
    int length = endingIndex - startingIndex;
    if (length > 1)
    {
        int leftSearchIndex = startingIndex + length / 2 + length % 2;
        int rightSearchIndex = endingIndex;
        float leftSearchValue = inputArray[leftSearchIndex];
        float rightSearchValue = inputArray[rightSearchIndex];
        if (leftSearchValue > targetValue)
        {
            return findTarget(inputArray, startingIndex, leftSearchIndex, targetValue);
        }
        else if (rightSearchValue > targetValue)
        {
            return findTarget(inputArray, leftSearchIndex + 1, rightSearchIndex, targetValue);
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else if (inputArray[startingIndex] > targetValue)
    {
        return startingIndex;
    }
    else if (inputArray[endingIndex] > targetValue)
    {
        return endingIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

__global__ void findTargets(float* inputArray, int numSubElements, int numTrajectories)
{
    int tId = threadIdx.x + (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x);
    while (tId < numTrajectories)
    {
        int beginIndex = tId*numSubElements;
        int endIndex = beginIndex + numSubElements - 1;

        float randomNumber = 0.5; //static for simplicity
        float searchVal = inputArray[endIndex] * randomNumber;

        findTarget(inputArray, beginIndex, endIndex, searchVal);
        tId += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }

}

int main()
{
    //Initiate example data
    int numTrajectories = 1000000;
    int numSubElements = 100;
    int totalNumElements = numSubElements*numTrajectories; // Size of vector
    thrust::host_vector<float> rVec(totalNumElements);
    thrust::host_vector<float> rVec2(totalNumElements);
    fillArrayWithRandom((float *) &rVec[0], totalNumElements);
    fillArrayWithRandom((float *) &rVec2[0], totalNumElements);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_vec = rVec;
    thrust::device_vector<float> o_vec(totalNumElements);
    thrust::inclusive_scan(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), o_vec.begin());

    //GPU timing
    warmUp <<<1, 1 >>>();
    int threadsPerBlock = 1024;
    float time_spent_GPU, time_spent_CPU;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventCreate(&start));
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventCreate(&stop));
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventRecord(start, 0));
    findTargets <<< (numTrajectories + threadsPerBlock - 1)/threadsPerBlock, threadsPerBlock >>>((float *) thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec.data()), numSubElements, numTrajectories);
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventRecord(stop, 0));
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventSynchronize(stop));
    gpuErrchk(cudaEventElapsedTime(&time_spent_GPU, start, stop));

    cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
    if (error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CUDA error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(-1);
    }

    time_spent_GPU = (double)(time_spent_GPU / 1000);
    double avg_GPU = time_spent_GPU / numTrajectories;
    printf("Avg. GPU Simulation Time: %.17g [sim/sec]\n", avg_GPU);

    //CPU Timing
    clock_t begin_CPU, end_CPU;
    begin_CPU = clock();
    float* rightPointer = &rVec2[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < numTrajectories; ++i)
    {
        float randomNumber = 0.5; //static for simplicity
        float searchVal = rightPointer[i*numSubElements + numSubElements - 1] * randomNumber;
        findTarget(rightPointer, i*numSubElements, i*numSubElements + numSubElements -1, searchVal);
    }
    end_CPU = clock();
    time_spent_CPU = (double)(end_CPU - begin_CPU) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    double avg_CPU = time_spent_CPU / numTrajectories;
    printf("Avg. CPU Simulation Time: %.17g [sim/sec]\n", avg_CPU);
    printf("CPU/GPU Timing:%.17gx \n", avg_CPU/avg_GPU);

    return 0;
}
```

My compiler options/output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: speedTest, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  Compiling CUDA source file kernel.cu...
1>  
1>  C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\speedTest\speedTest>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin" -rdc=true -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include"     --keep-dir Release -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static -DCUB_CDP     -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi  /MD  " -o Release\kernel.cu.obj "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\speedTest\speedTest\kernel.cu" 
1>  kernel.cu
1>C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/speedTest/speedTest/kernel.cu(124): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/speedTest/speedTest/kernel.cu(139): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>  
1>  C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\speedTest\speedTest>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -dlink -o Release\speedTest.device-link.obj -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi  /MD  " -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\lib\Win32" cudart.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib cudadevrt.lib  -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=sm_50  --machine 32 Release\kernel.cu.obj 
1>  cudart.lib
1>  kernel32.lib
1>  user32.lib
1>  gdi32.lib
1>  winspool.lib
1>  comdlg32.lib
1>  advapi32.lib
1>  shell32.lib
1>  ole32.lib
1>  oleaut32.lib
1>  uuid.lib
1>  odbc32.lib
1>  odbccp32.lib
1>  cudadevrt.lib
1>  kernel.cu.obj
1>  LINK : /LTCG specified but no code generation required; remove /LTCG from the link command line to improve linker performance
1>  speedTest.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\speedTest\Release\speedTest.exe
1>  copy "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\cudart*.dll" "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\speedTest\Release\"
1>  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\cudart32_65.dll
1>  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\cudart64_65.dll
1>          2 file(s) copied.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I would be very suspicious about using `raw_pointer_cast` on a host vector. Try something as prosaic as `float* rightPointer = &rVec2[0]`

Comment: Thanks, ya I just tried doing that (updated the code as well).  Unfortunately doesn't to seem to have done the trick.  What boggles me is that I can't put a breakpoint that's honored on anything in the for loop.

Comment: It works fine for me in VS 2012. What are your build/debugging properties like? (Just to show, this is the output when compiled and run in debug mode:
Avg. GPU Simulation Time: 8.0629449783486962e-009 [sim/sec]
Avg. CPU Simulation Time: 1.2300000662435195e-007 [sim/sec]
CPU/GPU Timing:15.254972836183555x
)

Comment: Interesting, thank you - not sure what's going on.  I just posted my compiler options/output.  Also, I tried updating my Thrust installation at "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" with the latest from Github by simplying replacing the "Thrust" folder - perhaps that could have potentially caused me issues?

Comment: Just tried replacing the "Thrust" directory with the old Thrust to no avail.  Also, tried removing the "-DCUB_CDP" option I had from using the CUB library earlier.

Comment: You keep saying that the code isn't running, but I see no evidence this is the case. Your host running is low resolution and compiler optimisation can eliminate lines of code which a source debugger would want to attach break points to. How about trying something as simple as running a small case and printing out the results? This place isn't a e debugging service and this equation is of no benefit to anyone except you. I've voted to close this and I encourage others to do the same.

Comment: Whoa now, arguably help to most code-related questions on SO could be classified as a "debugging service" but nonetheless, you were correct.  I just checked with a printf() statement and it turns out this does appear to be a compiler optimization issue.  I've never ran into this problem before and I suspect there may be others like me in the future that may benefit from seeing this case.  The reason I asked in the first place was that I didn't understand what was going on and it doesn't seem obvious to me anyways...

Comment: Just did a little more digging.  Turns out the "printf" was actually initiating a series of events that the compiler otherwise completely cuts out of the end binary.  Storing the output in an array completely changed the program's behavior (i.e. actually executed the for loop) and the GPU version seems to be over ~1000x faster.

Comment: Scratch that, ~38x times faster. The compiler was making the same optimizations for the GPU code, had to update it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the compiler was actually smart enough to realize that I wasn't doing anything with the host-side "findTarget" routine so it completely cut it out of the compiled code - i.e. it wasn't even being executed (hence explaining why dramatically increasing the simulation count did nothing and breakpoints weren't honored).

Answer (score 1):

As talonmies already pointed out, the clock resolution is in ms. Don't use it. Instead, try using boost chrono. Using it directly in cuda is a problem, so use the following as a header (`Timer.h`):

```
void startTimer();
void endTimer();
double totalTime();
```

with the cpp being

```
#include "Timer.h"
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>

// Nanoseconds
boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start, finish;

void startTimer()
{
    start = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

void endTimer()
{
    finish = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

double totalTime() {
    return (finish - start).count() / (1e9);
}
```

Then replace

```
begin_CPU = clock();
```

with

```
startTimer();
```

and

```
end_CPU = clock();
```

with

```
endTimer();
```

and

```
time_spent_CPU = (double)(end_CPU - begin_CPU) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

with

```
time_spent_CPU = totalTime();
```

This results in

```
Avg. GPU Simulation Time: 1.7804799301579521e-010 [sim/sec]
Avg. CPU Simulation Time: 6.4100000264286083e-013 [sim/sec]
CPU/GPU Timing:0.0036001529238579829x
```

(Note that I'm running other things on my GPU at the moment, so the numbers might not be too relevant)

Comment: Thank you - downloading the Boost library now, will report back as soon as it's finished.

Comment: Turns out it's not a timing issue, so much as a subtle compiler optimization (it got rid of the for loop code completely because it wasn't being used else where).  Thanks for the high-resolution timing code though, I'll be sure to start using that instead of clock().